# Swift | FSCalendar

Tags: ios, swift

Мне необходимо добавить соответствующие выделения для конкретных дней (массив приходит с сервера) в FSCalendar.

Пытаюсь сделать это следующим образом:
import UIKit
import FSCalendar

```
class AppointmentCreateThirdVC: UIViewController {
    
    var datesWithEvent = ["2021-02-13", "2021-02-18", "2021-02-08", "2021-02-05"]

    fileprivate lazy var dateFormatter2: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
    }
    

}

extension AppointmentCreateThirdVC: FSCalendarDataSource, FSCalendarDelegate, FSCalendarDelegateAppearance {
    
    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
        let dateString = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)

        if self.datesWithEvent.contains(dateString) {
            print("just one")
            return 1
        }
        
        return 1
    }
```

// пробовал и так:

```
    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, subtitleFor date: Date) -> String? {
        let dateString = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)

        if self.datesWithEvent.contains(dateString) {
            return "available"
        }
        
        return ""
    }
```

// и так:

```
    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, fillDefaultColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {
        print(date)
        let dateString = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)
        if self.datesWithEvent.contains(dateString) {
            return UIColor.blue
        }
        return UIColor.white
    }
}
```

На календаре пусто - https://i.stack.imgur.com/03lMV.png (хотя я ожидаю, что будут выделения или добавлен сабтайтл)

1. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?
2. Не совсем понимаю, для чего нужна функция numberOfEventsFor. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы назначили delegate и dataSource?

Comment: Да, назначил. В сториборде

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Оказывается у моего ViewController каким-то образом "слетел" класс, где была реализация календаря. Указал класс и всё заработало как надо.